# NgModel does not get updated inside NgFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to understand ngModel behaviour inside ngFor loop. I've created simple stackblitz to show the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zaq8zs

When i type something in the first input i see the same value in the second one and also the second input gets focus. I know it can be fixed by adding trackBy property and set it to index instead identity check, but I'm trying to figure out why this is happening.

If I understand correctly:

1. List is initialized with [null,null,null,null]
2. I type something in first input which casues the list change: ['1', null, null, null].
3. Angular then decides to add one container at the beginning and remove the last container.
4. The first container now becomes 2nd (thats why the focus is there).

But why am i seeing the same value in the second input? Whats interesting is that:

```
{{index}} {{list[index]}}
```

shows valid values, so i guess it has something to do with ngModel not being updated. Any ides why is it happening ?

Answer (score 0):

using `list[index]` in `ngFor` as `model` is not logical, in this case when you try to edit the input actually you want to change the `array` directly instead `model`; because of that you will get conflicts between your objects in array and it's not different if you even create array like `[1,2]` OR `[{},{}]`.

Angular logic using `let item of **` which mean `let item` to binding the object:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of list'>
      <input [(ngModel)]='item'> {{item}}
```

There is a **but** ***(not recommended)***:

> if you define the array as below, and then implement a `property` in this case `number` to your model it will works to you.

```
list = [{number: 1}, {number: 2}]

<div *ngFor='let item of list;index as index'>
      <input [(ngModel)]='list[index]["number"]'> {{item | json}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the `ngModel` is not updating. In fact the model is perfectly updating, what is being experienced here a problem of changing references in the object in the optimization of `*ngFor` structural directive

> To reduce DOM-manipulation to a bare minimum, angulars' ngFor directive is heavily optimized. 
> For example, if a element is added to the array, it is not re-rendering the whole list. Instead, all the existing DOM-elements are re-used and only the additional element is created.
> The same thing happens when a element is removed from the array. 
> Furthermore, when a element changes its position in the array, angular notices that and only changes the position of the one DOM-element. 
> To do all that optimization though, angular needs a way to identify each object in the array. Otherwise it cannot determine what happened. By default, it uses the reference of the object for that.
> For example when working with a REST-API or **using immutable data structures, the reference of each object changes all the time**.
>
> To prevent that behavior, we can help angular with the **identification of each object, by providing a so-called trackBy function**. With this function, we can tell angular, which properties cause an object to be unique. 
> Source : [Angular NgFor: Everything you need to know](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngfor/)

### Example

consider below sequence of events

- Current state of dom produced using *ngFor

```
<input value='' >
<input value='1' >
<input value='' >
<input value='2' >
```

- Now enter The value 5 in the 1st input

```
<input value='5' >
<input value='1' >
<input value='' >
<input value='2' >
```

- The information angular has is that the input structure was `<input value='' >` so it will go and look for the element with that structure, the Third element if found and angular updates this.

```
<input value='5' >
<input value='1' >
<input value='5' >
<input value='2' >
```

Now update Element 2 to 12, Angular checks the element whose structure was `<input value='1' >`, finds non and does nothing

```
<input value='5' >
<input value='12' >
<input value='5' >
<input value='2' >
```

Comment: I still don't get it, I mean i understand that angular uses already rendered DOM-elements but why `{{list[index]}}` part gets updated and value in the input does not? (you can check it in my stackblitz).